# moviepy.editor - upright video is wider not even

Tags: moviepy, video-editing

I have written code in moviepy.editor to make a video file smaller. The video is upright and is made wider by the image editing. Do I have a possibility to influence this image change?

**MY CODE**

```
import moviepy.editor as mp

def resize_video(input_path, output_path, target_framerate, target_bitrate):
    # load video
    video_clip = mp.VideoFileClip(input_path)

    # target framerate
    video_clip = video_clip.set_fps(target_framerate)

    # safe video
    video_clip.write_videofile(output_path, fps=target_framerate, codec='libx264', preset="medium", bitrate=target_bitrate)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_path = "foo.mp4"
    output_path = "bar.mp4"

    target_bitrate = "22794k"  # target bitrate in kbps
    target_framerate = 30  # target framerate in fps

    resize_video(input_path, output_path, target_framerate, target_bitrate)
```

[**VIDEO before**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ICPw.jpg)

```
video_clip.aspect_ratio = 1.7777777777777777
video_clip.size = [1920, 1080]
```

[**VIDEO after**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFLGf.jpg)

```
video_clip.aspect_ratio = 1.7777777777777777
video_clip.size = [1920, 1080]
```

I tried with other codecs, presets, bitrates and framerates. Nothing worked.